# How to enable/disable plugins dynamically in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to enable/disable plugins dynamically in WordPress (not using the admin)?

Example: I have a script to detect mobile devices, and I want to disable certain plugins accordingly. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Use the deactivate_plugin and activate_plugin functions.

Take a look at the post *[Disable plugin / plugin action via theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12163/disable-plugin-plugin-action-via-theme)* (on Stack Exchange site *[WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour)*).